# EF 6 Adding row limit automatically

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, where-clause, rownum

I have this below very simple function which returns list of rows from a table.

```
public IEnumerable<Configuration> GetConfigurations()
{
   var tbl = Context.Configurations.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.ActiveFlag == 'Y').ToList();

   return tbl;
}
```

Issue is sometimes when IIS app-pool restarts, the above code creates below SQL:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
"Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
"Extent1"."VALUE" AS "VALUE", 
"Extent1"."DESCRIPTION" AS "DESCRIPTION", 
"Extent1"."ACTIVE_FLAG" AS "ACTIVE_FLAG", 
"Extent1"."CATEGORY_ID" AS "CATEGORY_ID"
FROM "SCHEMANAME"."CONFIGURATIONS" "Extent1"
WHERE ('Y' = "Extent1"."ACTIVE_FLAG")
WHERE (ROWNUM <= (50) );
```

Notice the last line in there, there is no reason it to be there. application starts throwing exceptions as "SQL command not ended properly" when it happens, Just restarting the app-pool fixes the issue automatically.

Anybody knows why Entity Framework 6.1.3 would add extra where clause without any reason there? I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework version="12.1.2400" with "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.1.24160419" package.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Oracle driver?

Comment: As per: [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) Seems I am behind one minor version. If you are asking about managed drivers.  Do you have reason to believe it could be the reason? thing is issue happens rarely so I don't have a concrete way of testing it if I upgrade.

Comment: As a workaround I have done this for now. Still don't know the cause. I will update here if problem doesn't show up in future.

    `Context.Configurations.Load(); 
            var tbl = Context.Configurations.Local.Where(a => a.ActiveFlag == Constants.CSS_TRUE).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Changed the way EF loads the 1st table when application loads after app pool recycle as below fixed the issues.

```
 Context.Configurations.Load(); 
 var tbl = Context.Configurations.Local.Where(a => a.ActiveFlag == 'Y').ToList();
```

Issue didn't happened again.